# Hosting E-commerce website in ELB with one SSL cert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I have an e-commerce website application running. I have 5 domains totally and only one of them uses SSL. The rest I load in port:80.
There are 2 instances behind the ELB and they both share a common EFS mount (/var/www/html)
One of the websites in Port:80 redirects my customers to collect payment to a separate domain which uses SSL.I have my SSL installed on the ELB as well. However, when the mentioned redirects happen, the site is not loading. 
For my listener configs, I configured as HTTP forwarding to HTTP, https(443) forwarding to https, then only, the domains are working.

This is a totally working environment with a single ec2, Since the ELB is not friendly, I am paying for ec2, elb and EFS.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using one cert, and having to do all the redirects and special configuration, consider using the [AWS Certificate Manager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html) to generate 5 *free* SSL certificates that can then be connected to the Elastic Load Balancer.

Use the ELB to terminate SSL for all domains, and then use only an HTTP listener for the back end instances.

This will greatly simplify your setup, and you get a dedicated SSL cert for all domains at no cost.

I use CloudFormation to setup a certificate with multiple domains. Here is an example:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Description" : "SSL V2",
  "Resources" : {
    "Certificate" : {
      "Type": "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate",
      "Properties": {
        "DomainName": "example.com",
        "SubjectAlternativeNames" : [ "*.example.com","example2.com","*.example2.com","example3.com","*.example3.com" ]
      }
    }
  },

  "Outputs": {
    "CertificateArn" : {
        "Value" : {"Ref":"Certificate"},
        "Description" : "Certificate ARN",
        "Export" : { "Name": "CertificateArn" } 
        }
    } 
}
```